# Mount volume to windows container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to mount a volume to windows container from docker-compose:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  builder:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.vsc-web
    container_name: test
    environment:
    - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1    
    volumes:
      - C:\Work:C:\data
    tty: true
```

However, when I try to run the container, I get the following error:

```
C:\Work\vsCommunityImages>docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe up -d
Creating test ... error

ERROR: for test  Cannot create container for service builder: invalid volume specification: '/c/Work:C:\data:rw'

ERROR: for builder  Cannot create container for service builder: invalid volume specification: '/c/Work:C:\data:rw'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Any idea what could be the cause? Both host and container are windows.

I'm using docker-compose version 1.24.0-rc1